# Can't set 360p video setting for streaming on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, video-streaming, screen-resolution

I'm working on a streaming app. I was able to set 240p, 480p and all other settings for the streamer data output, excepts 360p. This is how viewer's screen looks like with 360p setting:

[image]

I'm using HaishinKit as the streaming library (I don't think that's the problem). If I change the setting to 320 for width in setting360p, it works. This is my settings:

```
let setting480p: [String:Any] = {        
    return [
        "width": 480,
        "height": 854,
        "bitrate": 700 * 1024,
        "maxKeyFrameIntervalDuration" : 0.0,
        "profileLevel" : "kVTProfileLevel_H264_Baseline_AutoLevel"
    ]
}()

let setting360p: [String:Any] = {        
    return [
        "width": 360, //Works when changed to 320
        "height": 640,
        "bitrate": 700 * 1024,
        "maxKeyFrameIntervalDuration" : 0.0,
        "profileLevel" : "kVTProfileLevel_H264_Baseline_AutoLevel"
    ]
}()

let setting240p: [String:Any] = {        
    return [
        "width": 240,
        "height": 427,
        "bitrate": 700 * 1024,
        "maxKeyFrameIntervalDuration" : 0.0,
        "profileLevel" : "kVTProfileLevel_H264_Baseline_AutoLevel"
    ]
}()
```